# Android Facebook login: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm developing an Android app with Facebook integration. When testing from my emulator, my app redirects to the browser and opens up Facebook login with the following error:

```
Invalid Argument
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration
```

On signing in, it tries to go to the URL **fbconnect://success#access_token=AAEZB4..**
but fails.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you generate acess token for your application in facebook developer page?

Use this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Yes. I followed the tutorial precisely as in the official [Facebook Android developers site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/). When I tested on a device, I didn't get this error. Since I need to test NFC, I'm using the emulator with Open NFC, but I get this error before login.

Comment: Fixed it. Using the updated repo from github solved the problem.

Comment: @ask link to the repo plz ?